# Compiling for many linux distributions

Tags: linux, distribution, cross-compiling

in a short I'm gonna release an application written in OCaml and I was planning to distribute it by source code.

The problem is that the OCaml development system is not something light neither so common to have installed so I would like to release it also in a binary way for various operating systems.

- Windows makes no problem since I can compile it through cygwin and distribute it with the required dlls
- OS X is not a problem too since I can compile it and distribute it easily (no external dependencies from what I've tried)

When arriving to Linux problems arrive since I don't really know which is the best way to compile and distribute it. The program itself doesn't depend on anything (everything is statically linked) but how to cover many distributions?

I have an ubuntu server 10 virtualized with an amd64 architecture, I used this machine to test the program under Linux and everything works fine. Of course if I try to move the binary to a 32bit ubuntu it stops working and I haven't been able to try different distributions... are there tricks to manage this kind of issue? (that seems recurring)

for example:

- can I compile both 32 bit and 64 from the same machine?
- will a binary compiled under ubuntu run also on other distributions?
- which "branches" should I consider when  wanting to cover as many distros as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can generally produce 64 and 32 bit binaries on a 64 bit machine with relative ease - i.e. the distribution usually has the proper support in its compiler packages and you can actually test your build. Note that the OS needs to be 64 bit too, not just the CPU.
- Static binaries generally run everywhere, provided adequate support from the kernel and CPU - keep an eye on your compiler options to ensure this. They are your best bet for compatibility. Shared libraries can be an issue. To deal with this, binaries linked with shared libraries can be bundled with those libraries and run with a loader script if necessary.
- You should at least target Debian/Ubuntu with dpkg packages, Redhad/Fedora/Mandriva with RPM and SUSE/OpenSUSE with RPM again (I mention these two RPM cases separately because you might need to produce separate packages for these "families" of distributions). You should also provide a .tar.bz2 or a .run installer for the rest.
- You can have a look at the options provided by e.g. Oracle for Java and VirtualBox to see how they provide their software.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to release the source code under a free license.  You can package it for a couple distributions yourself (e.g. [Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/), [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingGuidelines)), then cooperate with other people porting it to others.  The maintainers will often do most of this work with only a few required upstream changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at building it in the [openSUSE Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/). Although run by openSUSE, this will build packages for:

- openSUSE SUSE
- Enterprise variants
- Mandiva
- Fedora
- Red Hat Enterprise/CentOS
- Debian
- Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can compile for both 32 and 64 bits from the same machine :
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html

Most likely a binary running on Ubuntu will run on other distributions, the only thing you need to worry about if it you are using shared libraries (especially if you use some GUI framework or things like that).

Not sure what you mean by branch, but if you are talking about distribution, I would use the most vanilla Ubuntu distribution...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you just package a 32 and 64-bit binary for .deb and RPM, that way you can hit most of the major distros (Debian, Fedora, openSUSE, Ubuntu).

Just give clear installation instructions regarding dependencies,  command-line fu for other distros, etc. and you shouldn't have much a problem just distributing a source tarball.